# How can I infer a scalar with 2D array as input in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am pretty new in Tensorflow. My job is to infer a scalar with `2d array` as input. My input has the `shape of (2,3)`, and the output is a scalar.

I implement the model as following :

```
my_model = Sequential()

input_layer = layers.InputLayer(input_shape = [2,3])
xs = np.array(
    [[1,1,1],
     [1,1,1]],
    [[2,2,2],
     [2,2,2]],
    [[3,3,3],
     [3,3,3]])

ys = np.array([1,2,3])
my_model.add(input_layer)
my_model.add(layders.Dense(64, activation = 'relu', name = 'layerone'))
my_model.add(layders.Dense(64, activation = 'relu', name = 'layertwo'))
my_model.add(layders.Dense(1, name = 'output'))

my_model.summary()
```

However, the output has the `shape (2,1)` instead of `(1,1)`.

How can I change the output shape to `(1,1)`?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Hi Heyi, please put your code here(not just a screenshot). Besides, what are the inputs and outputs? please define your problem with more details!

Answer (score 0):

Flatten your input shape into a vector of shape (6,) instead of (2,3). You can use Flatten layer right after the input layer. The rest should work with nothing else changed.

Comment: Hey,
that was my idea too at first but is there a way to do it without flattening the input shape?